# Pristine, Blank PDF (without Acrobat)

Tags: pdf, document, utility

I need to find or create one 8.5x11 inch blank PDF file that is as small as possible with minimal information embedded, but still a valid and stable PDF document. If at all possibe, I'd like to do this without Acrobat.

What is the best way to produce such a document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i would try this

- create empty html document
- open it with google chrome
- go for "print"
- choose "save as PDF" as the printer and "print"

:)
good luck

other thing on my mind is to run a simple PHP program using fpdf library, that would just create and output the pdf

Comment: The chrome save as PDF idea is the best one yet, it created a 708 byte file with no "Producer" application/company name or creation-date, etc. My previous smallest file size was 1,150 bytes. Not that the size itself really matters - I just want a clean-as-possible document to inject things into (experimenting). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Depending on how you do this the file might be bigger than 708. I created one empty.pdf of 4095 bytes with Chrome and another with size of 715 bytes.